# Suppress "Are you sure you want to delete..." dialogue when deleting items on SMB shares

Tags: finder, macos, smb, trash, dialog

When connected to an SMB share in Finder and deleting files or folders, this dialogue comes up:

[image]

I believe that the reasoning behind this dialogue is because deleted files don't go to a Trash or `.Trashes` folder, and so I think it's a good dialogue to have for most users. But when managing a large number of files in SMB shares frequently it can become very tedious and time-consuming to keep having to confirm each deletion. Power users really only need to see this once (the first time they delete something).

I am aware of the `cmd+d` keyboard shortcut for performing the delete function on this dialogue, which shaves off some time, but ultimately I'd like a way to suppress this dialogue completely.

How could I suppress these dialogues and make it so that when I delete something the "Delete" action is performed?

Comment: Have you tried using the Terminal command `rm` on the share to bypass the Finder altogether? Does this work for SMB shares? I don't have one to test with. :-) Type `man rm` in Terminal for options, and test, test, test, before you commit to large chunks of files.

Comment: Indeed, using `rm` can delete files without requiring confirmation. To integrate this into my use case and have it be as effortless as possible I created an Automator Quick Action with `rm "$1"` in a "Run Shell Script" action. When selecting a file in Finder, this shows up in the services menu, so I was able to assign a keyboard shortcut to it in System Prefs. When invoking it does take 1-2 seconds for the automator quick action to run, but it's still better than having to interact with the confirmation dialogue repeatedly. Should you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Terminal command `rm` to bypass the Finder altogether and suppress the GUI notification.

Check out the available options by typing `man rm`.